# Python 3 : Unexpected ValueError when converting hex to int

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

When I try to convert a string to bits, it doesn't always work, depending on completely esoteric conditions :

```
print( int('deadbeef', 16) )
>>> 3735928559

print( int('dead beef', 16) )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'dead beef'

print( int('hello wolrd', 16) )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'hello world'

print( int('helloworld', 16) )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'helloworld'
```

First it seemed like it just wouldn't work with strings containing spaces, but it actually doesn't work either with "helloworld" or anything the like. Then why would it ever work with "deadbeef" ?
I am completely lost o.o

Comment: take a look at the documentation here, this explains it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Comment: A hex string is a string that only contains the characters '0123456789abcdefABCDEF' and possibly a leading + or - sign.

Comment: "helloworld" is valid in base 33: `print(int('helloworld', 33))` which outputs `809608041709942`. Base 36 is the maximum you can have `int('z', 36)` is equal to 35.

Comment: It may help to further define what  you mean by _"convert a string to bits"_ and show us what you expect the result to be. Bits can be encoded to strings in many ways (decimal, hex, base64, binary for instance). `int('deadbeef', 16)` means you want a hex decode and that's what you got.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a string to a hex representation of its bits, that's not what `int(s, 16)` does. `int(s, 16)` tries to treat the characters of `s` as the base-16 representation of an integer. `'deadbeef'` contains only characters that are valid digits in base 16:

```
d = 13
e = 14
a = 10
d = 13
b = 11
e = 14
e = 14
f = 15

deadbeef = 13*16**7 + 14*16**6 + 10*16**5 + 13*16**4 + 11*16**3 + 14*16**2 + 14*16**1 + 15
         = 3735928559
```

None of your other strings have that property.

If you want hex digits corresponding to the bits representing a string, first, choose an encoding (UTF8, probably), then use something like [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('hello world'.encode('utf8'))
b'68656c6c6f20776f726c64'
```

Answer (score 0):

int( hex_value,16) is used to convert hex string to int. You are facing an error if you pass a invalid hex character.
For your use case of converting string to bits you can use **bitarray** module

```
import bitarray
ba = bitarray.bitarray()
ba.frombytes('Hi'.encode('utf-8'))
print ba
```